# External js script not working in View (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have external js script where for example I writing this code

```
    $('#save').click(function () {
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

In view I have button

```
 <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" id="save" value="Create"  style="border-radius:30px; background: #1d69b4; border-color: #1d69b4;width: 250px; color: white;" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right: 40px;" />
</div>
```

In header of View I put scripts like this

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/HTMLCanvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PatientDatabaseScripts/AddingPatient.js"></script>
```

When I click button, it does nothing, any alerts. In dev console no errors.

But when I write alert via function , and in button put code `onclick = "save()"`, all okay.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Did you inspect the actual HTML as to what the ID of `save` actually is? aspnet renames the ID of Controls dynamically. Google what `ClientID` or `ClientIDMode="Static"` do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you try to attach event handler on the DOM element which is not loaded yet.

The one thing that you can do is wrap your JS in a 'ready' block, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').click(function () {
      alert('Clicked');
    });
})
```